# How to display an image in the right upper corner of an input box

Tags: html, css

I have an input box

```
<span class="arrowDate"><input type="text" value="<?php echo $inputValue; ?>" id="<?php echo $id; ?>" class="datePickBox"  /></span>
```

What I want to achieve is to add via css and image with and arrow in the right hand corner of the input box. If I change properties to the image, the properties of the input box should remain the same. Basically the image should be a type of overlay for the input box, but do not know how to do this.

```
.datePickBox{
        font-size: 0.9em;
        border: 1px solid #DEDEDE;
        width: 270px;
        position:relative;
        right:0px !important;
        padding-right:20px;
}

.arrowDate{ background:url('../images/arrow.png') no-repeat right center; border:1px solid #DEDEDE;  }
```

Comment: What is not working? What do you mean by "overlay" exactly?

Comment: @pekka - The input box should basically look like a select box, with an arrow on the right hand side, should form part of the input box. Can't get the image to display within the input box, with overlay I mean floating above the input box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give your `<input>` a transparent background so the background of the `<span>` can shine thru and remove the border, because the border comes from the `<span>` in your case;

```
.datePickBox {
   background: none;
   border: none;
}
```

But your text will be over the background image, if long enough, so you can additionaly add a right padding as large as the image is wide.

```
.datePickBox {
   background: none;
   border: none;
   padding-right: 20px; /* bg image width */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the mark-up:

```
<span><input type="text" id="textInput" name="textInput" />&rarr;</span>
```

I used the CSS:

```
span {
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 30px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #ffa;
    text-align: right;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 1em;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    line-height: 30px;
    padding: 0 0.5em 0 0;
}

span > input {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 2em;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-radius: 1em 0 0 1em;
    border-width: 0;
    border-right: none;
    outline: none;
}
```

To give the following [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/7WhEg/).

It's worth noting that I explicitly chose to place the arrow *alongside* the `input`, instead of 'overlaying' it *above* the `input`. It's also possible to amend [my answer from the a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6010006/doing-a-input-type-text-with-css3-and-fixed-image-on-the-background/6010119#6010119) to create a comparable layout with a submit button alongside the input.

Answer (score 1):

> Can't get the image to display within the input box, with overlay I mean floating above the input box

you won't be able to get it floating above the text with `background-image`.

One way to do this would be to place the image next to the input field, and using relative positioning to move it above it.

CSS:

```
.boximage { position: relative; left: -40px; z-index: 2 }
```

HTML:

```
<input type='text'><img class='boximage' src='image.gif'>
```

Answer (score 0):

better use this

```
<span><input type='text' /><img src='datepicker.jpg' /></span>
```

change the css to meet your overlay.. remove the right border of the text box