# Textbox with search image using html5 and css3

Tags: html, css

I am doing first site using html5 and css3. To display text box with search glass image I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6010006/doing-a-input-type-text-with-css3-and-fixed-image-on-the-background) help and it works good like:
[image]

Here is the code:

**HTML**

```
<form id="header-search">
<input type="text" class="searchbox" /><input type="submit" class="button" value="" />
```

**CSS**

```
#header-search{overflow:auto;}

#header-search input.searchbox {
     -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
     -moz-border-radius: 5px;
     border-radius: 5px;
     border:1px solid #8e8e8e;
     background-color:#f5f5f5;
     height:16px;
     padding:4px;
     padding-right:28px;
     color:#4a4a4a;
     float:left;
 }

#header-search input.button{
    border:0;
    padding:0;
    margin:0 0 0 -24px;
    width:24px;
    height:24px;
    background:transparent url('your-search-icon-path-here') center center  no-repeat;
    float:left;
}
```

I need to show search image on right side of text box I tried to understand the CSS but I couldn't get it.

**Can you please guide me what is grouping image inside text box. How its display and positioning is being control as there was no property with display in CSS code ?**

How I can change its display from left side of text box ?

Thanks

Comment: If you want to write html5 as you said, you should use `type="search"` instead of `type="text"`. (But doesn't relates to your question)

Answer (score 1):

In the given example the padding make is confusing to calculate the actual width of the search box (Not too much confusing, but yeah a little bit).

So first of all look at this example I have made by modifying yours : [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/tgUAW/)

The actual thing happening here is that the button is arranging next to the input box. But we are forcing it to move in the left side by giving a margin of -24 (which is the width of image). So by reducing 24px of left margin makes it looks like in the text box. And now if we want to align the image to left then we can reduce the left margin to the width of the text box to make it look like in left.

```
margin:0 0 0 -200px;
```

Here 200px is the width of textbox.

[Example for Left Image](http://jsfiddle.net/tgUAW/1/)